# How can one keep account active

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, ledger, account

Do I need to maintain certain amount of balance in order to keep my account active?

Comment: This part of the question is good, could you change the title to that? It would be useful for other people as well

> Do I need to maintain certain amount of balance in order to keep my account active?

Answer (score 5):

**Active accounts**

For the first question, it depends on what you mean with "active". This term has at least two meanings in the context of Tezos. First, an implicit account (i.e. a Tezos account that is not associated with a smart contract: a regular account that is used to store and transfer tez) is either present or not in the [context](https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/glossary.html#context). The context contains a mapping from accounts (represented by their address) to their balance. If the balance of an account falls to 0 mutez, then it is removed from the context. However, this does not mean that the account is no longer usable. If someone sends a transaction to the account, increasing its balance from 0 mutez, then it is re-introduced in the context. Note though, that each such addition to the context has a "origination fee", currently set to 0.257 tez. This fee is payed by the sender of the transaction.

This is different from what the [Tezos whitepaper](https://tezos.com/static/white_paper-2dc8c02267a8fb86bd67a108199441bf.pdf), section 3.3.2, states:

> A contract needs a minimum balance of 1 to remain active. If the
>   balance falls below this number, the contract is destroyed.

This has since been changed.

There is another sense to the word "active", that relates to [baking](https://tezos.com/get-started/#bake-validate). A baker runs a node that validate blocks on the Tezos blockchain, and receives rewards for this service. If a baker is not reactive, it can become "deactivated": it will no longer be selected for baking and thus forgoes any potential rewards. You can read more about this [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html#active-and-passive-delegates).

**Trading**

The simplest way to start trading, if you do not yourself want to run a node and handle a wallet, is to trade using a crypto exchange such as [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/), [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/), [MXC](https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/mxc/) or [Binance](https://www.binance.com/). You can find a more complete list of exchanges [here](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/tezos/markets/).

If you want to handle your wallet and node yourself, then you should starting reading up on the [basics](https://tezos.com/get-started) and more specifically, how to [store and use Tezos](https://tezos.com/get-started#store-and-use).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Note that TSE is meant for technical answers and not trading kind of questions. I have edited the question to reflect that however thanks nonetheless for takinf the time to answer this point as well.

Answer (score -2):

In other to keep my account active, I need to maintain a certain amount of balance in my account.

Comment: This answer could use more detail in order to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Welcome to Tezos Stack Exchange! In order to improve the quality of your answers please make sure that you provide sufficient details so your answer is useful to the OP. You need to give details in the body of your answer and also provide references for the source of your infos if possible.